# .Net Core cannot read Azure Optional Claim - ipaddr

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, identity

In .Net Core 3.1, I found that it could not read the optional claim from Azure AD - ipaddr. Anyone have idea?

```
Identity token: XXX
Identity token: System.Security.Claims.Claim[]
Claim type: acct - Claim value: 0
Claim type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/authnmethodsreferences - Claim value: pwd
Claim type: auth_time - Claim value: 1592477364
Claim type: name - Claim value: tester
Claim type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier - Claim value: 9190dd08-eb99-4def-8b0e-a0a9488c650a
Claim type: sid - Claim value: dd60ea4e-cc4f-4668-aee0-393ffb3e4dc0
Claim type: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier - Claim value: IUUXhcy8YnK-X5x4Mxwvtxdi8H74eANcTnZj2ZmQxV4
Claim type: tenant_ctry - Claim value: HK
Claim type: tenant_region_scope - Claim value: AS
Claim type: http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid - Claim value: xxx30ae3-9092-49c9-bf6d-d74f680615e4
Claim type: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name - Claim value: tester01@xxx.onmicrosoft.com
Claim type: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn - Claim value: tester01@xxx.onmicrosoft.com
Claim type: uti - Claim value: YHjG3-pwckizlnGrWZhzAA
Claim type: xms_pl - Claim value: zh-HK
Claim type: xms_tpl - Claim value: en
```

Comment: @Vincent VC: Ctrl + K formats the selection as code.

Answer (score 0):

As you see here [OpenIdConnectOptions.cs](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectOptions.cs,5cc7fe6410c2ed93), it says:

```
ClaimActions.DeleteClaim("ipaddr");
```

That means that it will be deleted by the handler. You need to do
write something like:

```
options.ClaimActions.Remove("ipaddr");
```

To make sure The OpenIDConnect handler does not remove that claim.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail
about this topic: [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)